# How does Viddy implement downloadable filters?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5

There is a very cool iPhone app called Viddy where you can download filters to apply to videos.

How can they pack filters outside the app, and make them available to users via downloading?

Comment: I really would like to know how they have done this as well... any one have an idea?

Comment: How do you know that the filter code is outside the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, they do use shaders and they're downloaded from the internet.

- Download [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/download-ie3-mac.php) for Mac, connect your iPhone with Viddy installed.
- Check `Library/effects` folder in `Viddy.app`. You'll find `afx_1_0.xml` and `vfx_1_0.xml` files there.
- Download them to your Mac, open them and you'll find filters definitions there along with URL to download them.
- An example is [SOHO filter](http://cdn.viddy.com/fx3/production/effects/1/all/soho.vfx.preview.zip). [Download this file](http://cdn.viddy.com/fx3/production/effects/1/all/soho.vfx.preview.zip), open it and you'll see three files there: `shader.fx3` where shader is defined, `thumb.png` for thumbnail and `vignette.png` file, which is used for this shader as well.

We did use same approach in unnamed application, but we did encrypt all this information along with shaders itself to avoid analysis like this one :)

---

**Encryption, decryption example request in comment**

- Let's say you have `.fx` file with your shader (or any other file).
- Open Xcode and go to Build Rules where you can define build rule for `*.fx` files. Set it to run your `Custom script:` which can look like this one:

  ENC_KEY="your-encryption-key"

  ${PROJECT_DIR}/../Tools/bin/crypt -e -k $ENC_KEY -i ${INPUT_FILE_PATH} \
  -o "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.cfx"
- This script produces `.cfx` file, which has same content as `.fx` file, but is encrypted.
- `crypt` binary came from this project: [download crypt Xcode project](http://aptogo.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/CryptCommandLineTool.zip).
- [Download encrypted resource demo](http://aptogo.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/EncryptedResourceDemo.zip).
- Copy `EncryptedFileURLProtocol.*` and `NSURL+EncryptedFileURLProtocol.*` files into your project.
- In app delegate call this to register your protocol `[NSURLProtocol registerClass:[EncryptedFileURLProtocol class]];`
- And now when you do want to open encrypted resource, you have to use protocol `encrypted-file` instead of `file://`. This task handles `NSURL` category from demo project and you can simply use `[NSURL encryptedFileURLWithPath:@"/path/to/my/encrypted/file"]`.

It's pretty simple and you'll find most info you need in sample app (link above). Also you can mangle your encryption / decryption key in application, so, people have to think and the key is not easily readable. Now, when you access encrypted file via this `NSURL`, it's automatically decrypted for you in app. The decryption key is set in `sharedKey` in `EncryptedFileURLProtocol.m` file.

Comment: so you're saying that there is a file pointing to a url. when inside the app you can click download, which will download the specified file into the documents folder which is then used as filter properties to achieve a desired effect?

Comment: A bit off topic...  what interests me is how you encrypted the file and then decrypt the file your unnamed application to avoid users looking into the app. ive looking into other musical apps and been able to take the sounds off of it and replace it with my own sounds which was cool but something i dont wish for another user to be able to do as easily. How would one go about the encrypting and then decrypting process so the unnamed application can read it and therefor use it?

Comment: @Pavan - they simply download additional shaders from the web.

Comment: @Pavan added an example how to encrypt, decrypt in iOS app. Better download linked demo project and learn from it.

Comment: yeah that would be great.
because then i can have encrypted files in my sandbox, so if anyone looks inside it.. it wont be of any use except for the app itself.. since only the app can decrypt the encrypted file originally packaged with it to the app store. if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer to accommodate the extra request. I'll reward the bounty to you, as you've referenced to viddy explaining in detail how they've created their definitions and their urls which will help when i'm structuring my app. Thanks a lot Robert

Comment: Thanks, you're welcome. Feel free to ask more if you're unsure about anything.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to have an [in-app purchase](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html) that's just a document that describes an [image processing graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_graph_architecture). (Think of a nodal graph representation for something like Shake or Nuke.) For example, a glow is often implemented as a blurred image mixed with the original image. You could create a document which describes that processing graph. Once you've downloaded such a document into your app, you can implement it using [Core Image filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html), or write your own using [GLSL](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/glsl/), or even just straight CPU processing.

Comment: thank you for answer. ill look into the root of in app purchase... a user below has suggested for downloadable content through a url request which would i feel might be a quicker process for the user. I'll definitely look into adopting your approach for exclusive content etc in future apps. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to build the filters into the app itself, and have the in-app purchase simply unlock the ability to use them.

If you wanted to avoid the download time for all the additional images or other pieces needed, you could still include the code in the main app, and just download the extra resources needed. You can use something like [Urban Airship's IAP support](http://urbanairship.com/products/in-app-purchase/) to host & download the IAP resources. (You might also want to look into new features of iOS 6 in this vein.)

Comment: its not th case of unlocking a feature.. its more the case of, i dont wish for the app to be huge, and for certain filters to be downloaded to the app just the way viddy does it so the user can choose whether to install the add on or not. the app itself will increase inside whether its a file downloaded to the documents folder or not im not sure. What puzzles me is how new content downloadable like it is in the viddy app just works flawlessy without the need to update the application itself

Comment: I think I addressed the issue of downloading additional content for IAPs in the second half of my answer; you can have those pieces be hosted by, eg, Urban Airship, and have those be downloaded when the user buys your IAP.

Answer (score 0):

GLSL shaders may be downloaded in source code form and then to be used for processing. It gives very flexible way to create new filters after having app published. From another hand it might be enough just to update (download) additional filter data. For example, Instagram uses same color curve technique for most filters but with different curve data, so it they want, they will be able to update their filters online.

Answer (score 0):

Filter for videos also uses CIImage class like intagram application for images. See the link here:"http://www.icapps.be/face-detection-with-core-image-on-live-video/". Now filters can be download the filter (actually its In App Purchase happening).

Put the purchase/download method right beneath the case:

```
 case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
      [self ...];
```

so whats happening is purchase of filter for free which can be used on any video. Actually method is enabled to have filter after SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased.

Comment: So its an in app purchase which then allows the required documents to be downloaded where you can then call the methods that would handle the downloaded files? hmm its that simple?